# Bad background color for favourite questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The highlighting of questions with your favourite tags are a bit strange. The light red color makes it feel like the questions are deleted or something.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the color to the regular yellow one (the one used on Stack Overflow). It will be live after our next production build.